# implementting Next Previous in webview

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to creating a EPUB Reader,and i want to implement Next Previous in webview(html) for that i use this methods

```
webViewRead.scrollBy(0, 0);
webViewRead.scrollTo(0, webViewRead.getHeight());
```

but the problem is `webViewRead.getContentHeight()` is give me the perfect Content height of html file but it not display properly.

```
if(pageUP){
    webViewRead.scrollBy(0, 0);
    webViewRead.scrollTo(0, _webviewHeightIndex*webViewRead.getHeight());
    pageUP=false;
}

if(pageDown){
    webViewRead.scrollBy(0, 0);
    webViewRead.scrollTo(0, _webviewHeightIndex*webViewRead.getHeight());
    pageDown=false;
}
```

here the `_webviewHeightIndex` if index for page count witch is start from 0 to

```
webViewRead.getContentHeight()/webViewRead.getHeight();
```

it's not giving me the proper paging. is their any other way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [here](https://github.com/NightWhistler/HtmlSpanner) and [here](https://github.com/NightWhistler/PageTurner/tree/master/src/main/java/net/nightwhistler/pageturner) for epub reading application. This will help you.